# Unable to receive email after updating NLog version

Tags: c#, .net, logging, console-application, nlog

After updating the version of the bellow packages from version 4 to 5, can see the log file but am unable to receive email:

Nlog ---> updated to 5.2.7
Nlog.Extension.Logging ---> updated to 5.3.7

**Nlog config for email:**

```
  <target xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" name="mailLog1" slidingTimeout="true" bufferSize="120" 
   flushTimeout="600000">
      <target name="mailerror" xsi:type="Mail"
          smtpServer="..."
          from="..."
          to="..." 
          subject="Error occurred in App"
          body="An error occurred in App. No data have been sent for today." />
     </target>
```

When I reinstate the previous version, can receive an email!

Comment: When troubleshooting NLog then one should look in [NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging) for clues. Also enabling `"throwConfigExceptions": true` is a good idea. Maybe your application exits (or crashes) without doing flush/shutdown of NLog (not completing the sending of email). See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

Comment: Notice there are several [breaking changes with NLog v5](https://nlog-project.org/2021/08/25/nlog-5-0-preview1-ready.html). Example [LoggingRule Filters DefaultAction changed to FilterResult.Ignore](https://nlog-project.org/2021/08/25/nlog-5-0-preview1-ready.html#loggingrule-filters-defaultaction-changed-to-filterresultignore) that can lead to no output.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/5459